# What is the earliest recorded pun in the English language?

Tags: history, puns

So, I'll admit I love a good pun. Done correctly, it is humor for the clever that builds up rather than tears down. Plus, it beats an emetic in the right situation.

That said, I wonder how far back puns go.  My assumption is that all languages have puns, but even still, it would be fun to know how far back they go. Is there a commonly accepted "Ur-pun" that could be considered the first in the English language?

Comment: Great question, but it reminded me of: "*Humor can be dissected as a frog can, but the thing dies in the process and the innards are discouraging to any but the pure scientific mind*". (E. B. White)

Comment: Some fell on Stone-age ground.

Comment: “the first joke in human history was most likely a feigned tickle.”

Comment: *THE PUN ALSO RISES: How the Humble Pun Revolutionized Language, Changed History, and Made Wordplay More Than Some Antics*, By John Pollack, 212 pp. Gotham Books. Reviewed here: *The Pun’s Story* By P. J. O’ROURKE, Apr. 15, 2011 http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/17/books/review/book-review-the-pun-also-rises-by-john-pollack.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0

Comment: Does the 'earliest recorded pun in the English language' necessarily have to be found in books? Recording could have occurred much later than the pun itself?

Comment: "The first recorded pun was not recorded." http://fairlyspiritual.org/2012/10/21/a-brief-history-of-puns-be-warned/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puns go way back to [ancient Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun#History), and are found in the bible, and as some of the earliest books translated into English, may well be the source of the "first pun in English".

### *Beowulf*

*[Beowulf](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/britannia/anglo-saxon/beowulf/vitellius.html)* "is one of the very earliest poems in English and its first great literary masterpiece". It was written in Old English sometime between the 8th and 11th centuries.

A footnote in *[Beowulf: A New Translation for Oral Delivery](http://books.google.fi/books?id=BzYTt25fzfUC&pg=PR56&lpg=PR56&dq=beowulf%20puns&source=bl&ots=ufzU_TyjTL&sig=UM6flFRpwTFTIJkaga8e4aVMtLk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hfI6Uv2LBcXq4gTX1IHQAg&ved=0CIQBEOgBMAw#v=onepage&q=beowulf%20puns&f=false)* (2007) says:

> Beowulf criticism has devoted a lot of attention to Unferth ... The poet seems to think his name is allegorical and means "bad mind" or "evil mind": this is suggested by the way in which he puns on the names in lines 1165b-66b of the original, where he says that both Hrothgar and Hrothulf had faith in the mind (*ferhþ*) of Band Mind (*Un-ferþ*) - obiviously not a very smart thing to do.

### Bede

The footnote in *Beowulf: A New Translation for Oral Delivery* (2007) continues:

> Punning, incidentally, was very popular among the Anglo-Saxons. Bede's account of Pope Gregory the Great and the English slave boys in Rome is deservedly famous. (*Ecclesiastical History*, Book II, Chapter 1), and already by the end of the period the incompetent and hapless King Æþelræd ("Noble Counsel") had acquired the nickname *Unræd* ("Bad Counsel") - whence the name Ethelred the Unready, by which he is know today.

Bede completed the *[Historia ecclesiastica gentis Anglorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_ecclesiastica_gentis_Anglorum)* (in English: * Ecclesiastical History of the English People*) by around 731. He wrote in Latin, but an Old English translation was made, sometime in the ninth or 10th centuries.

### Chaucer

Geoffrey Chaucer (c. 1343 – 1400), known as the Father of English literature, also used puns in his poetry. ["Chaucer’s Cunt"](http://skepticalhumanities.com/2011/01/18/chaucers-cunt/) shows some of his puns in *Canterbury Tales* (1380s–1390s):

> Oddly, these statements are followed by quotes from *The Canterbury Tales* that belie them, for the word that Chaucer uses is not “cunt,” but “queynte.” “Queint,” as a noun, literally means “a clever or curious device or ornament” (*Middle English Dictionary*) or an “elegant, pleasing thing” (*Riverside Chaucer*). When used to refer to a woman’s genitalia, it is both a euphemism and a pun.

Comment: What a cunning runt he was :)

Comment: Does the 'earliest recorded pun in the English language' necessarily have to be found in books? Recording could have occurred much later than the pun itself?

Comment: It's not English, but there's an old pun from Homer where  Odysseus  uses the alias "NoMan" (or whatever Old Greek was for that) and the Cyclops cries out "NoMan is killing me."